# How to custom init an EAGLView?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

In my iOS project, `glView` ends up with height=0 and width=0 even though `CGRect frame` correctly gets the screen's dimensions in the previous line.

```
 - (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application {
        CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:frame
                                 pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                                 depthFormat:0 
                          preserveBackbuffer:NO 
                                  sharegroup:nil 
                               multiSampling:NO 
                             numberOfSamples:0
                      ];
      }
```

Is there some other way I need to create my `EAGLView *glView` in order for it to be `init`'ed properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add the glView to a UIWindow. Check out the app delegate code in the Cocos2D project templates.